# How to check for an empty field read into a VBA date

Tags: excel, vba

I have a VBA date variable reading and taking on the value of a field in Excel:

```
dim myDate as Date
myDate = MySheet.Range("A1").Value
```

Now, if A1 is empty, and I print the value o myDate it gives me

```
12:00:00 AM
```

How do I check for this in an IF statement? As in, what do I replace ??? with below:

```
if myDate = ??? then
    MsgBox ("There is nothing in the field")
Else
    MsgBox (myDate)
End If
```

Comment: You could use `IsEmpty` when getting the value in the first place. Or check `if myDate = 0`.

Comment: @BigBen `IsEmpty` only works with a `Variant` (only a `Variant` can be `Empty`); comparing the date to `0` would do it.

Comment: @Mathieu I meant checking if `Range("A1").Value` is empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to test `myDate`, you should declare it as of type `Variant`

```
Dim myDate As Variant
myDate = [a1]

If Not IsDate(myDate) Then
    MsgBox "There is no date in the field"
Else
    MsgBox myDate
End If
```

Or, you could test `[a1]` to see if it contains anything.

Answer (score 2):

Dates are really just a subset of `Double`, with a string representation.

Don't bother with string conversions, dates aren't strings anyway.

`12:00:00 AM` is the string representation of a `Date` with a value of `0`, so the simplest way to check is to compare against `0`.

But storing a cell value directly into a `Date` variable (or anything other than a `Variant` really) without first validating the cell's value, leaves you open to *type mismatch* errors the day you try to convert some `#VALUE!` error into a date, string, or number - you need to avoid both explicit *and* implicit type conversions when reading a cell value, and work with a `Variant`:

```
Dim cellValue As Variant
cellValue = Range("A1").Value
```

From this point on, any operation that assumes a type will throw a *type mismatch* if a conversion can't be made.

Since we want a `Date`, let's use the `IsDate` function to validate the type:

```
Dim dateValue As Date
If IsDate(cellValue) Then
    dateValue = CDate(cellValue)
Else
    ' not a date
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Use one of these 2:

- `If Len(Trim(myDate)) > 0 Then`
- `If Trim(myDdate) = vbNullString Then`

---

Just make sure you do **not** write:

- `If myDate = Null Then`
- `Dim myDate as Date : IsEmpty(myDate) Then`

---

`IsEmpty(myDate)` would always return False, because `myDate` is declared As `Date` and not As `Variant`. `IsEmpty()` only works with `Variant`, because only a `Variant` can be `Empty`.

Comment: `IsEmpty(myDate)` would always return `False`, because `myDate` is declared `As Date` and not `As Variant`. `IsEmpty` only works with `Variant`, because only a `Variant` can be `Empty`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variant:

```
Sub datetest()
    Dim mysheet As Worksheet
    Dim myDate As Variant

    Set mysheet = ActiveSheet
    myDate = mysheet.Range("A1").Value
    If myDate = "" Then
        MsgBox "A1 is empty"
    Else
        myDate = CDate(myDate)
        MsgBox myDate
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Beat me by 40 seconds

Comment: @RonRosenfeld  Consider **undeleting** your answer; it is really not the same as mine.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld no. Your answer was more idiomatic, using `IsDate` to check the variant; this answer will throw a type mismatch given a `#NA` cell error.

Comment: Undeleted.  Also edited to include possibility of checking `a1` directly.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon  I agree with you.